# How do I switch a node's view mode for AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax

I've programmatically created a new view mode called ajax.  Is there any way to force a node page to use that view mode if I'm making an AJAX call?  I know how to switch page and node templates when it's an AJAX call in template.php, but it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: As far as I know it's not standard Drupal feature. So, please, explain what do you want to do? What kind of AJAX call are you doing?

Comment: I'm loading my node page in certain parts of my site into a JQuery popup (i.e., via AJAX), and want a completely different layout when this happens - i.e. not just a different template, but a different view mode (so I can use different fields / field formatters). It might not be a standard feature, but it ought to be possible in my theme.

Comment: You can do this quckly on Drupal 8/9 like mentioned in my answer here : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/309563/61506

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom handler for your ajax request, I suggest you to manually render the node using [node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) api function. It has a view_mode parameter which you should set to 'ajax'.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with
>   Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like
>   REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal
>   site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the
>   same callback code.

### Features(3.x):

- Service API allow modules to create other services, including pluggable access control
- Server API allow modules to create other servers, such as SOAP
- Aliasing methods
- Integration with core Drupal functionality like files, nodes, taxonomy, users, files and more.  ***you can try this option***
- Response format API allows you to define response Formats for CONTENT-TYPE ie. application/json or application/xml. (also calls such as ENDPOINT/node/1.json work)

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not what I'm looking for. I've used Services before, and I don't believe this is a problem that will solve.