# Specify the view mode when the node is displayed on modal window (ajax)

Tags: 8, ajax

Is possible to specify the view mode using the default modal Ajax functionality?

I'm using this and it works, but I need to theme the node in a different way inside the modal

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/node/NID">Open Modal</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it will always show the full view mode, as you are linking to the canonical entity page - which is the page to see the full view mode. If you want to show a different view mode, then I would suggest creating a custom route (or path if you're using D7), and in the callback, generate the output programmatically with the view mode you want. I'd probably use the following for the path:

```
node/[NID]/teaser
```

And in there I would output the teaser view mode.

Comment: thanks for answering. I was just wondering if there are something already built on the default functionality. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8/9, you can do this quickly by [creating a routing entry](https://www.drupal.org/node/2056839).

For example, if i have a content type Program and i wish to load it with the view mode Dialog, i will create a `program.routing.yml` in my custom module `program` like this :

```
program.view:
  path: '/program/{node}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'node.dialog'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Then in my template, i will add this link :

```
<a class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" href="/program/[nid]">Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: What if you want to render a view in a modal in a customized way?